# App."Top Tags" != Website.Tags

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, profile-page, android-app

On the user profile of the Android app, the profile page has a field for Top Tags which is visually similar to the Tags field on the user profiles of the website. But, surprisingly, thats as far as the similarity goes.

The Tags field on a user profile on the website shows the **total score of non-CW answers** within a tag.

The Top Tags field (on the app) on the other hand shows the **total score of all questions and answers** within a tag.

I think that the two fields should be consistent across the site and app, in both naming and data shown. Or, if the *intention* was to show different data across the two fields, then the name of the app profile *Top Tags* field should be change to *Tag Participation* or something that clearly distinguishes it from the website profile Tags field.

Comment: Please see balpha's explanation on the older version of this report and feel free to add in your thoughts there.